# How to specify index column in Entitiy Framework Designer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce

I am currently working on my first project based on Entity Framework 6 with VS2012 using a SQL Server Compact database (model first).
Currently I am wondering how to declare an Entity column to be indexed (not unique values) in the database without being the primary key.

Thank you for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify an index through the designer. This can only be specified in the database, if you do Database-First, or through the model, if you do Code First. My preference is Database First, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: It is, however, possible to specify the index in the code.

Comment: @S.Dav yes, that's what I meant by "through the model, if you do Code First".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the  `Index` attribute to create Index on a particular column in the database as shown below:

```
class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
    }

    public int Student_ID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    [Index]
    public int RegistrationNumber { get; set; }
}
```

You can also specify it to be clustered with `IsClustered = true` and a unique index by specifying `IsUnique=true`.

```
[Index( "INDEX_REGNUM", IsClustered=true, IsUnique=true )]
public int RegistrationNumber { get; set; }
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx for details like unique indexes and multicolumn indexes.